# Perform aggregation to create new column based on criteria from 2 columns individually and also together

Tags: r, data.table

I need to create 2 different kinds of aggregations based on conditions on 2 columns, but it seems very complicated because whether to aggregate or not depends on the interaction between both columns.

The dataset looks like this:

```
dt = data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05",
                         "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-08", "2015-01-09", "2015-01-10",
                         "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05",
                         "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-08", "2016-01-09", "2016-01-10"),
                to_aggregate = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
                flag1 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
                flag2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA))

> dt
    id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2
 1:  1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA
 2:  1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA
 3:  1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA
 4:  1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA
 5:  1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA
 6:  1 2015-01-06            1    NA     1
 7:  1 2015-01-07            1    NA    NA
 8:  1 2015-01-08            0    NA    NA
 9:  1 2015-01-09            1    NA    NA
10:  1 2015-01-10            1     1    NA
11:  2 2016-01-01            0     1    NA
12:  2 2016-01-02            1    NA    NA
13:  2 2016-01-03            1    NA    NA
14:  2 2016-01-04            0    NA    NA
15:  2 2016-01-05            1    NA    NA
16:  2 2016-01-06            1    NA    NA
17:  2 2016-01-07            1    NA    NA
18:  2 2016-01-08            1    NA     1
19:  2 2016-01-09            0    NA    NA
20:  2 2016-01-10            1     1    NA
```

Expected results:

```
result = data.table(id = c(1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2,2),
                date = c("2015-01-01", "2015-01-02", "2015-01-03", "2015-01-04", "2015-01-05",
                         "2015-01-06", "2015-01-07", "2015-01-08", "2015-01-09", "2015-01-10",
                         "2016-01-01", "2016-01-02", "2016-01-03", "2016-01-04", "2016-01-05",
                         "2016-01-06", "2016-01-07", "2016-01-08", "2016-01-09", "2016-01-10"),
                to_aggregate = c(1,1,0,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,0,1,1,1,1,0,1),
                flag1 = c(NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1),
                flag2 = c(NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,1,NA,NA),
                aggregrate1 = c(NA,NA,NA,0.75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.67,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.78),
                aggregrate2 = c(NA,NA,NA,0.75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.75,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,NA,0.5))

> result
    id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2 aggregrate1 aggregrate2
 1:  1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
 2:  1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
 3:  1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA          NA          NA
 4:  1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA        0.75        0.75
 5:  1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA          NA          NA
 6:  1 2015-01-06            1    NA     1          NA          NA
 7:  1 2015-01-07            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
 8:  1 2015-01-08            0    NA    NA          NA          NA
 9:  1 2015-01-09            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
10:  1 2015-01-10            1     1    NA        0.67        0.75
11:  2 2016-01-01            0     1    NA          NA          NA
12:  2 2016-01-02            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
13:  2 2016-01-03            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
14:  2 2016-01-04            0    NA    NA          NA          NA
15:  2 2016-01-05            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
16:  2 2016-01-06            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
17:  2 2016-01-07            1    NA    NA          NA          NA
18:  2 2016-01-08            1    NA     1          NA          NA
19:  2 2016-01-09            0    NA    NA          NA          NA
20:  2 2016-01-10            1     1    NA        0.78        0.50
```

aggregate1: I need to find the average of to_aggregate from the first entry of an id to the next flag1==1, then the average of to_aggregate until the next flag1==1, by id.

aggregate2: If flag2==1 exists between two 1's in flag1, then I need to find the average of to_aggregate starting from the next row to the next flag1==1. [e.g. the second 0.75 and the 0.5 in aggregate2].

I am not even sure how to start because for aggregate1, how would I look through flag1 while averaging to_aggregate? And more frustratingly, how would I then consider if flag2==1 exists between two 1's in flag1?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, using two `grp` variables:

```r
dt[, grp1 := rev(cumsum(rev(fcoalesce(flag1, 0)))), by = id
  ][, aggr1 := c(rep(NA, .N-1), sum(to_aggregate)/.N),
     by = .(id, grp1)]
dt
#        id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1     aggr1
#     <num>     <char>        <num> <num> <num> <num>     <num>
#  1:     1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA     2        NA
#  2:     1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA     2        NA
#  3:     1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA     2        NA
#  4:     1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA     2 0.7500000
#  5:     1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA     1        NA
#  6:     1 2015-01-06            1    NA     1     1        NA
#  7:     1 2015-01-07            1    NA    NA     1        NA
#  8:     1 2015-01-08            0    NA    NA     1        NA
#  9:     1 2015-01-09            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 10:     1 2015-01-10            1     1    NA     1 0.6666667
# 11:     2 2016-01-01            0     1    NA     2 0.0000000
# 12:     2 2016-01-02            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 13:     2 2016-01-03            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 14:     2 2016-01-04            0    NA    NA     1        NA
# 15:     2 2016-01-05            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 16:     2 2016-01-06            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 17:     2 2016-01-07            1    NA    NA     1        NA
# 18:     2 2016-01-08            1    NA     1     1        NA
# 19:     2 2016-01-09            0    NA    NA     1        NA
# 20:     2 2016-01-10            1     1    NA     1 0.7777778
#        id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1     aggr1
```

and then

```r
dt[, grp2 := rev(cumsum(rev(fcoalesce(flag2, 0)))), by = id
  ][, aggr2 := fifelse(flag1 == 1, c(rep(NA, .N-1), sum(to_aggregate)/.N), NA_integer_), 
     by = .(id, grp1, grp2)]
dt
#        id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1     aggr1  grp2 aggr2
#     <num>     <char>        <num> <num> <num> <num>     <num> <num> <num>
#  1:     1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA     2        NA     1    NA
#  2:     1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA     2        NA     1    NA
#  3:     1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA     2        NA     1    NA
#  4:     1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA     2 0.7500000     1  0.75
#  5:     1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
#  6:     1 2015-01-06            1    NA     1     1        NA     1    NA
#  7:     1 2015-01-07            1    NA    NA     1        NA     0    NA
#  8:     1 2015-01-08            0    NA    NA     1        NA     0    NA
#  9:     1 2015-01-09            1    NA    NA     1        NA     0    NA
# 10:     1 2015-01-10            1     1    NA     1 0.6666667     0  0.75
# 11:     2 2016-01-01            0     1    NA     2 0.0000000     1  0.00
# 12:     2 2016-01-02            1    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 13:     2 2016-01-03            1    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 14:     2 2016-01-04            0    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 15:     2 2016-01-05            1    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 16:     2 2016-01-06            1    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 17:     2 2016-01-07            1    NA    NA     1        NA     1    NA
# 18:     2 2016-01-08            1    NA     1     1        NA     1    NA
# 19:     2 2016-01-09            0    NA    NA     1        NA     0    NA
# 20:     2 2016-01-10            1     1    NA     1 0.7777778     0  0.50
#        id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1     aggr1  grp2 aggr2
```

Basic walk-through:

- `fcoalesce(flag1,0)` is converting the `NA` to 0, prepping for the `cumsum` (which is a common/convenient function for grouping, along with `rleid` for different kinds). There are likely better ways to do this, perhaps `!is.na(flag1)` instead.
- `rev(cumsum(rev(.)))` is because we want the group to *end* on a `flag1==1`, not start. For instance, see the first five rows:

  ```r
  dt[1:5,]
  #       id       date to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1 aggr1  grp2 aggr2
  #    <num>     <char>        <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num> <num>
  # 1:     1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA     2    NA     1    NA
  # 2:     1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA     2    NA     1    NA
  # 3:     1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA     2    NA     1    NA
  # 4:     1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA     2  0.75     1  0.75
  # 5:     1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA     1    NA     1    NA
  ```

  if we did just `cumsum(.)` (no `rev`s), then `grp1` of 2 would stop at row 3, which is not where we want it. The double-`rev` allows us to keep that `flag1==1` occurrence in the "precending" (rows above) group.
- Once we have `grp1`, we now just get the average (`sum(.)/.N`, faster than `mean`, though I doubt that's important to you here). We need to do this for each `grp1` within `id`.
- The second build-up and aggregation is similar, though we need to group it eventually in `id`, `grp2`, *and* `grp1`, a slight change.

Comment: Thanks r2evans, it seems to work. Would it be too much trouble to ask you to provide a short explanation on what is going?

Comment: See my edit, hope it helps explain things.

Answer (score 1):

We can use `dplyr` methods.  Grouped by 'id', `replace` the NA elements of 'flag1' with 0 (`replace_na`), then the reverse cumulative sum with `revcumsum` from `spatstat.utils` and get the `mean` of 'to_aggregate' in the last row

```
library(dplyr) 
library(tidyr) 
library(spatstat.utils)
dt %>%
    group_by(id) %>%
    group_by(grp1 = revcumsum(replace_na(flag1, 0)), .add = TRUE) %>%
    mutate(aggr1 = case_when(row_number() == n() ~ mean(to_aggregate))) %>%
    ungroup
```

-output

```
# A tibble: 20 x 7    
#      id date       to_aggregate flag1 flag2  grp1  aggr1
#   <dbl> <chr>             <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
# 1     1 2015-01-01            1    NA    NA     4 NA    
# 2     1 2015-01-02            1    NA    NA     4 NA    
# 3     1 2015-01-03            0    NA    NA     4 NA    
# 4     1 2015-01-04            1     1    NA     4  0.75 
# 5     1 2015-01-05            0    NA    NA     3 NA    
# 6     1 2015-01-06            1    NA     1     3 NA    
# 7     1 2015-01-07            1    NA    NA     3 NA    
# 8     1 2015-01-08            0    NA    NA     3 NA    
# 9     1 2015-01-09            1    NA    NA     3 NA    
#10     1 2015-01-10            1     1    NA     3  0.667
#11     2 2016-01-01            0     1    NA     2  0    
#12     2 2016-01-02            1    NA    NA     1 NA    
#13     2 2016-01-03            1    NA    NA     1 NA    
#14     2 2016-01-04            0    NA    NA     1 NA    
#15     2 2016-01-05            1    NA    NA     1 NA    
#16     2 2016-01-06            1    NA    NA     1 NA    
#17     2 2016-01-07            1    NA    NA     1 NA    
#18     2 2016-01-08            1    NA     1     1 NA    
#19     2 2016-01-09            0    NA    NA     1 NA    
#20     2 2016-01-10            1     1    NA     1  0.778
```

---

Or a similar option in `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
dt[, grp1 := revcumsum(replace_na(flag1, 0)), id]
dt[, aggr1 := NA_real_]
dt[,  aggr1 := replace(aggr1, .N, mean(to_aggregate)), .(id, grp1)]
```